# Why FB.getLoginStatus or FB.login return access token and signed request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

`FB.getLoginStatus` returns `access token` and `signed request`. I've passed them both to server side, where I've decrypted `signed request`, got `code` and using the latter – requested Facebook for `access token`.

Both access tokens and their expiration time are the same.

Why do I need both of them? Should I use this somehow as a security feature by comparing the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are redundant, just two views of the same data. There is no point in comparing the two. If you want to be most safe, verify the signed request and throw out the whole set of data if it's not valid.

Personally I recommend using the fbsr_APPID cookie instead of manually passing the signed request. It's a tiny bit more obscure to people trying to poke around in your app.